# SQL Query For These Two Tables

Tags: sql, join, alasql

I have these two tables:

**Person**

```
Name    Gender  RegionID
Bob     Male    1
Mary    Female  2
Jane    Female  3
Chris   Male    1
Paul    Male    2
Matt    Male    2
Jenny   Female  1
```

**Region**

```
ID  Region  
1   North   
2   South   
3   Central
```

I would like to end up with a table like this:

```
Region  Male    Female
North   2       1
South   2       1
Central 0       1
```

I first tried to get the resulting table with the region's ID in there so no join required:

```
select RegionID, Gender, count(Name) from Person group by RegionID
```

But the Gender field is coming back undefined. And didn't really know where to go from there.

As tagged, I'm using the `alasql` JavaScript library.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Please state your RDBMS and: What have you tried so far? Hints are: `INNER JOIN` with the Region's ID, and `GROUP BY`

Comment: Tip: first do the join, then add GROUP BY. Use CASE expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at this:

```
SELECT A.Region
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Male' Then 1 else 0 end) Male
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Female' Then 1 else 0 end) Female
FROM Region A
Inner Join Person B
On A.ID = B.RegionID
Group By A.Region
```

Comment: I'd do left join, to get 0 in case a region has no persons.

Comment: I agree with you. That is if he still wants to show it with zero value just to show what regions there are but if he wishes to show only those with a persons then he can stick with inner join. @Submits it's your choice.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
select region 
,sum(case when b.Gender='Male' then 1 else 0 end) Male
,sum(case when b.Gender='Female' then 1 else 0 end) Female
from Region a
inner join Person b on  a.[Id]=b.RegionID
group by a.[Id],a.Region
order by [id]
```

In tsql you can pivot, which might be easier if you have more than a couple of values to pivot on:

```
Select * from 
( select Region ,Gender
  from Region a
  inner join Person b on  a.[Id]=b.RegionID ) p
pivot
( count(Gender)
for Gender 
IN ([Male],[Female])
) pivottable
```

If you add a third gender, nonbinary like this

```
insert into Person values ('Kim','Nonbinary',3)
```

You can easily extend you query to account for that:

```
Select * from 
( select Region ,Gender
  from Region a
  inner join Person b on  a.[Id]=b.RegionID ) p
pivot
( count(Gender)
for Gender 
IN ([Male],[Female],[Nonbinary])
) pivottable
order by a.[id]
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the final solution in `alasql`, this is what I came up with thanks to the help from this page:

```
var res = alasql("SELECT regionData.Title \
                        , SUM(CASE WHEN peopleData.Gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male \
                        , SUM(CASE WHEN peopleData.Gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female \
                        FROM ? regionData LEFT JOIN ? peopleData \
                        ON regionData.ID = peopleData.RegionID\
                        GROUP BY regionData.Title", [regionData, bensData]);
```